# Expected value of stopping time of Stochastic Process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $X$ be the strong solution of the following Stochastic Differential Equation:
$\mathrm dX_t = sign(X_t)dt + \mathrm dW_t, X_0 = 0$, where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian Motion. Let $\tau = inf\{t \geq 0: |X_t| \geq 1\}$. Compute $E[\tau]$.

Note that a strong solution does exist (see Shreve Stochastic Calculus and Brownian Motion pg 341).

I have tried looking for a solution with absolute values but couldn't get anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas for this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this an exercise from a book? Using Tanaka's formula one can show that $$|X_t| = \int_0^t sgn(X_s) \, dB_s + t + L_t^0(X)$$ where $L^0(X)$ denotes the local time of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ at level $0$. But unfortunately I don't see how to get rid off the local time ...

Comment: This is a problem on an old qualifying exam.